# Density of pixels in android

Tags: android, pixel, dpi

If I have android device with 5 inches diagonal screen size and 2.3 inches screen width and its screen supports 1080*1920 pixels what is the nearest type of its screen density? How can solve this question?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `sp` for font sizes and `dp` for anything else. See this SO post regarding screen density, terminology, and proper uses: [Difference between px, dp, dip and sp in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android/2025541#2025541)

Also, here is a link to the android developer's API guide for supporting multiple screens in your applications: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

You can find out device display info reading [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) from Activity

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

int dpi = dm.densityDpi;
```

`dm.densityDpi` will give you device dpi bucket expressed in dots-per-inch

You can also get other display metrics like:

```
float density       - The logical density of the display - scaling factor
float scaledDensity - A scaling factor for fonts displayed on the display.
int widthPixels     - The absolute width of the display in pixels.
int heightPixels    - The absolute height of the display in pixels.
float xdpi          - Physical pixels per inch of the screen in the X dimension.
float ydpi          - Physical pixels per inch of the screen in the Y dimension.
```

However, for some devices `xdpi` and `ydpi` metrics are returning wrong numbers and you cannot rely on them. Since API 17 you can also use `getRealMetrics()`. It should give you accurate values for `xdpi` and `ydpi`.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(dm);
```